# Intellij cannot resolve methods of classes from external library

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am working with the IBM Watson service and imported the library through a maven dependency.

I assumed everything went fine, as all the classes are shown in the external library section:

[image]

Instantiating classes works fine, but if I try to use methods from those classes Intellij says "cannot resolve symbol 'methodname'".

```java
public class Watson
{

    ConversationService service = new ConversationService("2017-07-02");
    service.setUsernameAndPassword("username", "password");
    NaturalLanguageClassifier n = new NaturalLanguageClassifier();
    n.createClassifier()

}
```

I have already tried the invalidate caches action and tried other tricks I could find on the internet, but nothing worked... What do I do wrong? Is there any option I have to tick so that Intellij finds the methods?

Comment: please post code using markup, not as image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the 4 lines within a method. For simplification, I put it in `main`.

```java
public class Watson
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConversationService service = new ConversationService("2017-07-02");
        service.setUsernameAndPassword("sss", "ttt");
        NaturalLanguageClassifier n = new NaturalLanguageClassifier();
        n.createClassifier("name", "en", new File("/tmp/data"));

    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, I cannot belive I was too blind to see that... Thanks a lot for the help!